# Why doesn't Logistic Regression require heteroscedasticity and normality of the residuals, neither a linear relationship?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, linear-model, assumptions

I was reading this [link](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/free-resources/directory-of-statistical-analyses/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/) when I got stuck trying to understand. Not even Wooldridge in Introductory Econometrics, or O'Reilly Data Science from Scratch explored this question. And I was surprised I couldn't find any explanation for this question. So, the problem is related to Logistic Regression assumptions. Why doesn't Logistic Regression require the error and linear relationship assumptions that Linear Regression require?

I will try to explain better, but if the question get messy, the title is the short question and the thing that got inside my head... So, I know that Logistic Regression is about category targets, but the regression actually predicts the probability of an event/category, right? Isn't that something that would require linear relationships?

Regarding the errors, the normality assumption isn't required because the errors will be zero or 1? I thought some assumption would be required, so we don't get any bias (e.g.: we have a logit to predict if someone will pay the debt, but our model gets most of NYC people prediction right, but not from NJ, idk).

Well, I think my question got a little messy because I tried to explain better, but hopefully, people will understand and the assumptions will be more explored than most tutorials we have.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you understand why (Gaussian) linear regression has those assumptions in the first place?

Comment: @Firebug that's a good point, but I think I do. I mean, it's hard to write in here, but I agree with the answer from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54533/what-do-normal-residuals-mean-and-what-does-this-tell-me-about-my-data. Heteroscedasticity is about the estimators not being BLUE. I guess I understood (but I wouldn't disagree that I might have some gap, idk)

Comment: I just asked so answers could use that theory to answer. If you understand that linear regression is intrinsically a Gaussian conditional expected value estimator, then following that logic logistic regression is a Bernoulli conditional expected value estimator. Then, you see how that links to Gaussian residuals in linear regression, while no analogue happens for logistic regression.

Comment: "Isn't that something that would require linear relationships" - I don't follow. Why would estimating/predicting probability require linearity? could you clarify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Isn't that something that would require linear relationships?

The assumption is that the effect of covariates is linear on the log odds scale.  You might see logistic regression written as

$$ \operatorname{logit}(p) = X \beta $$

Here, $\operatorname{logit}(p) = \log\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)$. Additionally, remember that linearity does not mean straight lines in GLM.

> Regarding the errors, the normality assumption isn't required because the errors will be zero or 1?

Not quite.  Logistic regression estimates a probability, the error (meaning observation minus prediction) will be between 0 and 1.

> Why doesn't Logistic Regression require the error and linear relationship assumptions that Linear Regression require?

Logistic regression is still a linear model, it is just linear in a different space so as to respect the constraint that $0 \leq p \leq 1$.  AS for your titular question regarding the error term and its variance, note that a binomial random variable's variance depends on its mean ($\operatorname{Var}(X) = np(1-p)$).  Hence, the variance chances as the mean changes, meaning the variance is (technically) heteroskedastic (i.e. non-constant, or at the very least changes based on what $X$ is because $p$ changes based on $X$).